# Jframe suddently not visible anymore

Tags: java, jframe, visibility, jlist

I was building a musicplayer. Everything worked out perfect. But when I tried to add a `JList` to my second `JPanel` it all failed.. The file compiles and does run the program in command prompt.. I think.. But the program does not show up.

Even though I haven't touched the `window.setVisible(true);` visible line.

Can anybody see the mistake?

This is the code:

```
/**
 * Created by Natalie89dk on 02-11-2016.
 */
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame {

    public Frame(){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setTitle("Player");
        window.setBounds(200, 10, 500, 300);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        window.setVisible(true);

        JPanel playlistList = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        playlistList.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        window.add(playlistList, BorderLayout.WEST);

        GridBagConstraints contain1 = new GridBagConstraints();
        JLabel label11 = new JLabel("Playlists");
        contain1.gridx = 0;
        contain1.gridy = 0;
        contain1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        playlistList.add(label11, contain1);

        JButton createPlaylist = new JButton();
        createPlaylist.setText("Create playlist");
        contain1.gridx = 0;
        contain1.gridy = 1;
        contain1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        playlistList.add(createPlaylist, contain1);

        DefaultListModel<String> listModel = new DefaultListModel<String>();
        JList<String> list = new JList<String>(listModel);
        contain1.gridx = 0;
        contain1.gridy = 2;
        contain1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        playlistList.add(list, contain1);

        String playlist1 = "Playlist1";
        String playlist2 = "Playlist2";
        String playlist3 = "Playlist3";
        String playlist4 = "Playlist4";
        String playlist5 = "Playlist5";
        String playlist6 = "Playlist6";
        String playlist7 = "Playlist7";
        String playlist8 = "Playlist8";
        String playlist9 = "Playlist9";
        String playlist10 = "Playlist10";
        String playlist11 = "Playlist11";
        String playlist12 = "Playlist12";

        listModel.addElement(playlist1);
        listModel.addElement(playlist2);
        listModel.addElement(playlist3);
        listModel.addElement(playlist4);
        listModel.addElement(playlist5);
        listModel.addElement(playlist6);
        listModel.addElement(playlist7);
        listModel.addElement(playlist8);
        listModel.addElement(playlist9);
        listModel.addElement(playlist10);
        listModel.addElement(playlist11);
        listModel.addElement(playlist12);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        //scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
        contain1.gridx = 0;
        contain1.gridy = 3;
        contain1.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        playlistList.add(scrollPane, contain1);

        JPanel currentPlaylist = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        currentPlaylist.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        window.add(currentPlaylist, BorderLayout.EAST);

        GridBagConstraints contain = new GridBagConstraints();

        JLabel label12 = new JLabel("Playing playlist");
        contain.gridx = 0;
        contain.gridy = 0;
        contain.insets = new Insets(10, 10, 10, 10);
        currentPlaylist.add(label12, contain);

        JButton addTrack = new JButton();
        //addTrack.setSize(new Dimension(100, 30));
        addTrack.setText("Add Track");
        // window.add(addTrack, BorderLayout.EAST);
        contain.gridx = 0;
        contain.gridy = 1;
        contain.insets = new Insets(10, 4, 10, 10);
        currentPlaylist.add(addTrack, contain);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Player();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the `Player` class contain?

Comment: Oh.. I missed the Player.. I've just changed new Player to new Frame..  And it works.. Thanks a lot. (:

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is difficult is that an exception is being thrown and you aren't seeing it.  Try wrapping your call to new Player() inside a try/catch of "Exception" and print out the results.

Although this doesn't directly answer your question, it will give you the answer and will also help you in the future :)

This is a common thing you need to remember to check for whenever you have a run() type of method that operates asynchronously.

Java doesn't force you into any particular logging facility, but "main" defaults to logging exceptions to standard error (System.err).  This is ONLY the behavior of the main method and has nothing to do with Java! An exception thrown from "Frame" (Such as the fact that it isn't a JFrame) does not happen until after the invokeLater has returned--so main physically can't handle the exception since it has already exited before the exception occurred (invokeLater returns immediately before the code has run).

When you are running a thread exceptions that escape your run() method just stop thread execution and the stack trace is silently consumed.  There is the concept of an uncaught exception handler that could easily do the job, but by default it does nothing.

You must generally deal with asynchronous exceptions yourself or they will go completely stealth and stealth exceptions is one of the biggest developer time wasters in Java.

Comment: Alright.. I've just found out what I did wrong, as you can see in my comment above. But I will try to implement the try catch exception anyway. Thank you very much for your advise. (:

Answer (score 0):

I think it may be caused because you have not used the extend JFrame on the class frame.

Example:

```
 public class Frame extends JFrame{}
```

Comment: Just did that. It didn't solve it though. (: But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your class is called `Frame`, not `Player`.

Replace this:

```
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Player();
                    }
```

with

```
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        new Frame();
                    }
```